# Call the same 'migrate' command a lot of times in Artisan Command

Tags: php, laravel

I have a command that will call a 'migrate' command a lot of times, with different configs to each one. That's my code:

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$host", $root, $root_password);
$databases = $pdo->query('SHOW DATABASES')->fetchAll();

foreach($databases as $db){
  $dbName = $db['Database'];

  Config::set('database.connections.my_database.database', $dbName);
  $this->call('migrate', array('--env' => 'local', '--database' => 'my_database')); 
}
```

Since I have dynamic creation of Databases in my Application, I made this command to run migrations for all my databases. So, first I get all database names, and call 'migrate' command to each one. But I have a problem.

Artisan is running the migrations only to the first $dbName. Even if I print correctly $dbName to each step of the loop, the other ones display "Nothing to migrate". If I try to run the command for the others databases in the terminal, it works perfectly. It seems like a cache, I don't know.

Does anyone have any idea about what is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that I need to reconnect the DB connection in each step of loop. So, code will be:

```
foreach($databases as $db){
  $dbName = $db['Database'];

  Config::set('database.connections.my_database.database', $dbName);
  DB::reconnect('my_database');
  $this->call('migrate', array('--env' => 'local', '--database' => 'my_database')); 
}
```